# Flutter: How to set easy_localization logging log level

Tags: flutter, dart, import, localization, dart-pub

I want to set the log level of [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) in a Flutter application. I tried to do this by setting the EasyLocalization.logger.defaultLevel enum, however the enum is stored in the local Pup cache and I couldn't find a good way to import it into the file to get access to it.

I tried setting a integer value and casting to dynamic but this did not work either.

Is there a way to import this enum, or otherwise set the log level with this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) is using the [easy_logger](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_logger) package to print log messages.

If you want to set the log level for easy_localization you also have to add the easy_logger package.
To do so run:

```bash
flutter pub add easy_logger
```

Now you can import the easy_logger package and access the `LevelMessages` class:

```dart
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:easy_logger/easy_logger.dart';

void main() {
  EasyLocalization.logger.defaultLevel = LevelMessages.info;
}
```